# Antithetic Sampling for variance reduction in graph convolutional network (GCN)

Tags: python, sampling, montecarlo, variance, gnn

I am trying to implement [Antithetic Sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antithetic_variates) to sample vertices of the graph and train the downstream graph convolutional network (GCN) model on the sampled graph.

> Antithetic Sampling is a variance reduction technique that involves
> generating pairs of random samples and their corresponding antithetic
> counterparts to cancel out fluctuations, leading to more accurate
> estimates.

Below is my code and function '_Antithetic_sampling(...)' is main function to implement the logic of Antithetic Sampling.:

```
import math
import torch
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp

from scipy.sparse.linalg import norm as sparse_norm
class Antithetic_Sampler(Sampler):
    def __init__(self, pre_probs, features, adj, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(features, adj, **kwargs)
        col_norm = sparse_norm(adj, axis=0)
        self.probs = col_norm / np.sum(col_norm)
    def sampling(self, v):
        """
        Inputs:
            v: batch nodes list
        """
        all_support = [[]] * self.num_layers  # Initialize empty list for all layers
        cur_out_nodes = v 
        for layer_index in range(self.num_layers - 1, -1, -1): # Start from the last layer and move backwards
            cur_sampled, cur_support = self._Antithetic_sampling(cur_out_nodes, self.layer_sizes[layer_index])  # sample nodes and collect support
            all_support[layer_index] = cur_support # for corresponding layer, Store current support in all_support 
            cur_out_nodes = cur_sampled # Update nodes 
        all_support = self._change_sparse_to_tensor(all_support) # Convert support to tensor representation       
        sampled_X0 = self.features[cur_out_nodes]  # Extract features of the sampled nodes 
        return sampled_X0, all_support, 0

    # Perform Antithetic Sampling
    def _Antithetic_sampling(self, v_indices, output_size):
        support = self.adj[v_indices, :]
        neis = np.nonzero(np.sum(support, axis=0))[1]
        # Create two sets of random sampling weights
        p1 = self.probs[neis]
        p1 = p1 / np.sum(p1) # Normalize probability 
        p2 = 1 - p1
        p2 = p2 / np.sum(p2)

        # Sample the first set of neighbors
        sampled_1 = np.random.choice(np.arange(np.size(neis)), output_size, True, p1)
        u_sampled_1 = neis[sampled_1]
        support_1 = support[:, u_sampled_1]
        sampled_p1 = p1[sampled_1]
        support_1 = support_1.dot(sp.diags(1.0 / (sampled_p1 * output_size)))

        # Sample the second set of neighbors with opposite weights

        sampled_2 = np.random.choice(np.arange(np.size(neis)), output_size, True, p2)
        u_sampled_2 = neis[sampled_2]
        support_2 = support[:, u_sampled_2]
        sampled_p2 = p2[sampled_2]
        support_2 = support_2.dot(sp.diags(1.0 / (sampled_p2 * output_size)))

        # Average two sets of sampled neighbors
        u_sampled = (u_sampled_1 + u_sampled_2) // 2
        support = (support_1 + support_2) / 2
        #print("U samples: ",  u_sampled)
        #print("Support: ",  support)

        return u_sampled, support
```

Output of this code is:

> epchs:0~9  => test_loss: 1.882, test_acc: 0.319

> epchs:10~19  => test_loss: 1.879, test_acc: 0.319

> epchs:20~29  => test_loss: 1.876, test_acc: 0.319

> epchs:30~39  => test_loss: 1.879, test_acc: 0.319

> epchs:40~49  => test_loss: 1.871, test_acc: 0.319

> epchs:50~59  => test_loss: 1.873, test_acc: 0.319

It can be observed that test accuracy is not changing, which indicates that there might be a logical mistake in my implementation of Antithetic Sampling. Comments in the code provide details of each step, and I've included links to relevant sources for reference. I'm **looking for** help to identify the mistake in my implementation.

> More details about Antithetic Sampling can be found [here](https://www.math.arizona.edu/%7Etgk/mc/book_chap5.pdf) and [here](https://artowen.su.domains/mc/Ch-var-basic.pdf) (section 8.2).

Comment: What do we know about the data format? For instance in this class, `Antithetic_Sampler(Sampler)` how can one create an object to test your code?

Comment: Please provide a minimal piece of code that replicates your issue. This is really hard to debug without the rest of the code.

Comment: Be careful with this: `all_support = [[]] * self.num_layers`. Python will actually create 1 list which contains 1 list and N references to the original list. Use `all_support = [[] for _ in range(self.num_layers)]` instead (which creates a new list object N times, instead of a copy)